# Aptana and python package management

Tags: python, django, ide, aptana, anaconda

I am using Aptana Studio for Django development. I need to use the Pillow package but though its installed I am always getting the exception that module not found.
When I try

```
pip list
```

It is showing that the package is there.
I have Anaconda installed in my system and have tried

```
conda install pillow
```

It shows as a installed package when I do

```
conda list
```

But still I am getting the error.
I am using Python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Check your Pillow package version because `Pillow < 2.0.0 supports Python versions 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7; Pillow >= 2.0.0 supports Python versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3`

perhaps you may need to update the package using

```
pip install -U Pillow
```